# How helpful will an SSD be to my boot time?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

I have a 7200 RPM HDD with my windows 10 on it. It takes about 18 seconds for the bios to boot, and an additional 12 for windows. If i'm correct The SSD would only reduce that 12 seconds down, not the extra 18 that's slowing it down. If I wanted to speed up my boot by a lot would I need a new motherboard with a faster BIOS, or are there some settings I can turn on to speed it up?

Comment: 18 seconds is very long for just the BIOS. Are you sure you're not counting part of the Windows boot as bios time? And yes, the disk type won't have a relevant effect on bios boot time.

Comment: No, the 12 seconds is from where it shows loading windows, the rest is BIOS.

Comment: So 18 seconds you're on the screen that says something about pressing a key (probably F2) to enter BIOS settings? Or are some of these 18 seconds on a screen that shows the computer brand and a rotating circle of white dots at the bottom?

Comment: Windows 10 has got naughty. It uses the BIOS logo while it boots. Out of the 18 seconds, only 3-4 seconds are used by the BIOS.

Comment: @YashasSamaga I don't believe that is even possible... his 18 seconds in BIOS is probably because he has BIOS delay turned on, a common feature to slow down BIOS startup so it's features can be accessed or information can be seen. Either that, or the BIOS is having issues detecting or configuring a piece of hardware.

Comment: @acejavelin Well, my Windows 10 PC uses my ASUS UEFI BIOS screen logo with the Windows waiting circle below it. After that, the login page appears. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/eonswy

Comment: @acejavelin check this [Windows 10 uses UEFI BIOS Splash logo for its boot logo](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/175900-Win-10-uses-UEFI-BIOS-splash-logo-for-its-boot-logo)

Comment: @YashasSamaga Oh, OK. I see what your saying... That isn't really the BIOS screen though, at least it shouldn't be... it 'should' be an OEM Windows logo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boost your BIOS by enabling "fast boot" and reducing the splash screen showing up time.

Fast boot will disable some of your motherboard checkups. Most of them aren't needed for home workstation.

Spash screen is the motherboard manufacturer's logo displayed instead of the older BIOSes' text output. This screen is showing up between 0 and 20s, depending on hardware and settings, and is meant to catch the "setup" keypress (F1, F2, DEL, or so). If you set this timer to 0, the sreen won't show up and you'll have to press the "setup" key before powering up your PC.

Then, switching to a SSD isn't really needed, because your OS booting time is already low, and the cost of a SSD isn't worth 5 or 6s of boot time !

Comment: I have the splash set to the lowest it can go, and where might I find "fast boot"

Comment: what is your motherboard brand/model ? and what is your BIOS (or UEFI) verison ? We can't help you without these infos.

Comment: It's an Intel q43 antelope, not sure about the bios version though.